# Could not locate the bindings file. Tried while using serialport in electron env

Tags: node.js, binding, electron

I am trying to build my electron-serial app in linux ENV, and first I have rebuild the electon with serialport

`electron-rebuild -f -w serialport`

everything work well, seems the rebuild execute sucessfully

```
...

⠸ Building module: bindings, Completed: 0  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bindings/src/serialport_linux.o
⠼ Building module: bindings, Completed: 0  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bindings.node
⠧ Building module: bindings, Completed: 0  COPY Release/bindings.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/party/code/geeCom/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build'
```

but when I build my app via webpack, and try to start it, I got the `Could not locate the bindings file. Tried` issue.

here are the whole error traces

```
npm start

> gee-com@0.0.1 start /home/party/code/geeCom
> electron ./app/main.js

App threw an error during load
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/build/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/build/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/build/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/out/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/out/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/build/default/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/compiled/12.18.3/linux/x64/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/addon-build/release/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/addon-build/debug/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/addon-build/default/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/lib/binding/node-v85-linux-x64/bindings.node
    at bindings (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:2309:9)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/linux.js (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:544:91)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3713:41)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/index.js (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:385:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3713:41)
    at Object../node_modules/serialport/lib/index.js (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3507:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3713:41)
    at /home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3731:20
    at /home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3767:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3769:12)
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/build/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/build/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/build/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/out/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/out/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/build/default/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/compiled/12.18.3/linux/x64/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/addon-build/release/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/addon-build/debug/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/addon-build/default/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/party/code/geeCom/lib/binding/node-v85-linux-x64/bindings.node
    at bindings (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:2309:9)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/linux.js (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:544:91)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3713:41)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/index.js (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:385:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3713:41)
    at Object../node_modules/serialport/lib/index.js (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3507:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3713:41)
    at /home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3731:20
    at /home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3767:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/party/code/geeCom/app/main.js:3769:12)
```

the result seems the serailport pkg still do not in electron env?
does any one got same issue? could U share me any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

sence I notice electron try to find bindings file in these path, so I copy the build `bindings.node` to `geeCom/build/`, it can start. but seems not a perfect method..